# Nanocomposite hydrogel for wet adehsion in biomedical applications

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, materials, nanotechnology, adhesion

My name‘s Tristan and I‘m a bachelor‘s student in Germany. I‘m trying to synthesize an injectable nanocomposite hydrogel for wound closure and wound healing applications. The problem is that, next to bioactive glass nanoparticles, I‘d like to incorporate chitosan or carboxymethyl chitosan (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijbiomac.2018.09.131) as a biopolymer matrix but I don‘t know how to get it to adhere to tissue in wet environments. I‘ve been researching catechol/quinone chemistry as an option for functionalization, since it is said that those groups could adhere to virtually anything (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijbiomac.2021.02.091). Therefoe I want to try to synthesize some adhesive polydopamine or tannic acid (because of its gallol moieties) hydrogels. I‘ve already tried an approach with tannic acid (https://doi.org/10.1021/acsami.0c02037), which has failed to adhere in wet environments and I‘m now looking for a viable approach inculding polydopamine.
However, I now don‘t really know how to specifically functionalize chitosan to get it to properly adhere to tissue in wet environments. Does anyone of you have an idea about a method or substance that could do the job?

Greetins from Germany:)